# A phrase to describe "implementation of an order in all the cases"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

To a query, an order has been given by the higher authority. Now, it is a question as to whether the same order should be implemented in all the cases. In this scenario, what phrase should be used?

Comment: Your usage is fine. You might ask (using your words): "Is the same order to be implemented in other all other cases as well?"

Comment: If there is a base class that implements the order, then you can ask whether all other cases _inherit_ the implementation. If the cases are choices within a multi-case switch, you can ask whether implementing the order is a _precondition_ to handling all cases.

Comment: @PapaPoule I just restored "as to whether" in the question. It should not have been deleted in the second edition.

Answer (score 4):

An appropriate phrase is **across the board**.  Here's an example of the usage as applied to a decision about raises as reported in 2000 by the US [National Labor Relations Board](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZBVn_rspfrUC&q=%22across%20the%20board%22&dq=%22top%20out%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYjZ6FyO3JAhXKdz4KHVkgB9s4ChDoAQgrMAM):

> This evidence strongly suggests that the parties intended the initial
>   agreement to include increases for top out employees<sup>*</sup> only in the
>   second and third years. The Union claims, based on some additional
>   bargaining history evidence, that the contract language was intended
>   to provide **across the board** raises for all three years of the contract.

The term is [said](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/across-the-board.html) to originate in betting on horse races when people bet all three winning spots -- win, place, and show -- on horses named on the betting boards of odds makers.

*a *top out employee* is one already at the top wage level in the company.

Answer (score 1):

You could use various expressions such as:

- Does this apply to every case?
- Should this order be implemented in every case?
- Are all cases subject to this order?

Answer (score 0):

According to *Merriam-Webster*, a “[standing order](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standing%20order) is:

> an instruction or prescribed procedure in force permanently or until
>   changed or canceled;      especially :  any of the rules for the
>   guidance and government of parliamentary procedure which endure
>   through successive sessions until vacated or repealed.

In your scenario, you could ask your boss:

"Should we/I consider your recent response to our/my inquiry to be a **standing order** to be followed in all [such] cases?"

Or simply:
"Is this a **standing order**?"